Correct syntax rendering variables within command string
Been trying to learn some better scripting in bash.  Normally I can pull data values to iterate into command strings,  but this one is showing my ignorance on syntax.
#! /bin/bash
while IFS=',' read name_c1 ip_c2
do
echo "Name:" $name_c1
echo "file:" v1-$ip_c2.yaml
export file=v1-$ip_c2.yaml
# cat $file
/usr/bin/incus launch images:debian/12/cloud $name_c1 -p prod-mgt --config=cloud-init.network-config=$(cat $file)

done < <(tail -n +1 host-list)

When I just echo the variables they render fine,  but when rendering them from the command string, something is off.  If I simplify the command string to just "/usr/bin/incus launch images:debian/12/cloud $name_c1"
Here is the output I get:
Name: c1
file: v1-192.168.0.222.yaml
Error: yaml: unmarshal errors:
  line 1: cannot unmarshal !!str `c2,192....` into api.InstancePut

I know my syntax is off most likely,  any clues to what I need to change to render those variables pulled from the host file?
Example of the host-list file for clarity:
c1,192.168.0.222
c2,192.168.0.221
c3,192.168.0.220
c4,192.168.0.219
c5,192.168.0.218
c6,192.168.0.217

Thank you

Run shellcheck on your script. It gives very helpful hints on possible problems.

btw, according to the incus documentation the syntax to read the config from a file is < filename.

The command that works from cli - incus launch images:debian/12/cloud c11 -p prod-mgt --config=cloud-init.network-config="$(cat v1-192.168.0.217.yaml)"
However running: incus launch images:debian/12/cloud "$name_c1" -p prod-mgt --config=cloud-init.network-config="$(cat $file)"
gives me: Error: yaml: unmarshal errors:
line 1: cannot unmarshal !!str c2,192.... into api.InstancePut
ran it through shellcheck and cleaned it up a bit.

Some things to try:
First, add some debugging options to the sheebang declaration:
#! bash -vx 

That will display each line as it executes, with the expanded variables.
Second, in more complex scripts, consider adding a "safe mode" flag:
SAFE = ""
# SAFE = "echo :: "  # Make this conditional on your favourite "debug" flag. 

Then add this before any command you execute.
${SAFE} /usr/bin/incus launch images:debian/12/cloud $name_c1 -p prod-mgt --config=cloud-init.network-config=$(cat $file)

That way, you can run and test the script-y bits without invoking all the "dangerous" bits.
Finally, if your intention is to loop through the lines in the host-file, I think your loop construct is a bit suspect.
Try something like this:
while IFS=',' read name_c1 ip_c2
do
   echo "Name:" $name_c1
   echo "file:" v1-$ip_c2.yaml
   
   . . . 
   
done < host-list 


Found out incus reads from stdin by default, so that was messing me up.
Slightly better version:
#! /bin/bash
while IFS=',' read -r name_c1 ip_c2
do
    file=v1-$ip_c2.yaml

    cat >> "$file" << EOF
network:
  version: 1
  config:
    - type: physical
      name: eth0
      subnets:
        - type: static
          address: $ip_c2/24
          gateway: 192.168.0.1
          dns_nameservers:
            - 192.168.50.50
            - 192.168.0.1
          dns_search:
            - example.com
EOF

incus launch images:debian/12/cloud "$name_c1" -p prod-mgt --config=cloud-init.network-config="$(cat $file)" < /dev/null
done <  host-list

rm v1-*
exit

Thanks for all the input!
